# Setting checkstate on a ListWidgetItem

Tags: qt4, pyqt4, maemo

I'm trying to create a list of checkbox items that change the status on activation. I can connect the activate signal and everything seems to work, but changes on the screen. Am I missing some steps here?

Here's the list creation:

```
self.listField = QtGui.QListWidget(self)

muted_categories = qb.settingsCollection['mutedCategories'].split('|')
main_categories = sorted(set(qb.categoryTopNames.values()))

for category in main_categories:
   item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem(category, self.listField)
   item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
   if category in muted_categories:
      item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
   else:
      item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

self.listField.connect(self.listField, QtCore.SIGNAL('itemActivated(QListWidgetItem*)'), self.doItemChangeState)
```

and here's the handler:

```
def doItemChangeState(self, item):
   """ invert the state of the activated item """

   if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
      item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
   else:
      item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
```

I verified that the handler is fired after clicking - if I put prints there, it will alternate "checked" / "unchecked". What can I do to refresh the checkboxes themselves?

Edit: tried calling update() and emitting the itemChanged signals... no luck so far.

Answer (score 2):

I can't test this just now, but...  I was under the impression that PyQt4 handled the screen updates automatically when items were checked/unchecked (at least, it does for QCheckBox items).  It *looks* to me like your event handler is actually undoing the user's action.  Have you tried commenting out the self.connect line and running again?

As I understand it, setCheckState() is really intended for setting the default state of each item...